# MySQL: Insert data into table, some data comes from another table (relational)

Tags: mysql, insert, relational-database, insert-update

I want to run the following two queries in one:

```
SELECT id FROM user_settings WHERE ......
$id = id_from_query_above();
$value = 100; // this could be anything
INSERT INTO user_config (sid, value) VALUES($id, $value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=$value
```

(notice that I want to update if a row associating to the primary key has already been inserted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO user_config(sid, value)
    SELECT id, $value
    FROM user_settings
    WHERE ......
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = $value;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you - I didn't know I could use the `SELECT` statement with non-table rows (i.e `$value`). Is it possible to do something similar with multiple insertions/ updates?

Comment: This will do multiple insertions.  I don't know what the question is about updates, but subqueries are allowed in `update` queries too.

Comment: I meant updates if the row has been inserted. Could you provide an example where this query can insert 2 rows?

Comment: @KeirSimmons . . . That is an example.  The `select` can return multiple rows.

Comment: So what about the value of `$value` (as this would be different for each insertion)?

Comment: @KeirSimmons . . . You need some way of setting that.  It would be a constant.  Perhaps you should ask another question, this is getting a bit far from this question.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll create the question now, thanks for your help :) .