# MySQL: Insert multiple rows of data into table, some data comes from another table (relational)

Tags: php, mysql, insert, relational-database, insert-update

Additional question to [MySQL: Insert data into table, some data comes from another table (relational)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816260/mysql-insert-data-into-table-some-data-comes-from-another-table-relational/24816332?noredirect=1#comment38524034_24816332)

My question above basically asked "how can I insert a row into a table, using information found in another row". The answer was to use a query such as:

```
INSERT INTO user_config(cid, sid, value)
SELECT $cid, id, $value
FROM user_settings
WHERE mid='$mid' AND name='$name'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = $value;
```

My problem now is, I need to insert multiple rows. For each row I need to insert, there is a different value for `$cid`, `$value`, `$mid` and `$name`. For example I could run the following (pseudo):

```
function x($cid, $mid, $name, $value){
    // run query:
    INSERT INTO user_config(cid, sid, value)
    SELECT $cid, id, $value
    FROM user_settings
    WHERE mid='$mid' AND name='$name'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = $value;
}

x(1,'a','b');
x(2,'c','d');
x(3,'f','e');
```

Problem is, that would run 3 queries, and I want to be able to do this in one. Is it possible? I could provide an array for `$cid`, `$mid` and `$name` if that helps the problem?

Comment: 1- why do you want to do it in 1 query instead of 3. 2- you have `$value` in your query, but do not have it as a function parameter, where is `$value` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, `$value` is a parameter (just edited my question). I will be calling this function relatively regularly and therefore want to reduce the number of queries I have to run on a page load.

Comment: Why don't you try writing a procedure that iterates through your array?

Comment: You can count the number of times you will run the query and then if there is more than 2 queries, just make 2 different queries, one getting the results, other inserting evrything :P

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the information in the x calls is expressible as a select on various tables in your database. Your list of x calls looks le a table whose columns are $cid, $mid, $name, $value, right? (Your x calls should have 4 arguments not 3.)

Give the definitions of the tables and a query that produces the x arguments as a table with columns cid, mid, name, value.

Then modify the select in your question so that that x select is in the FROM. Of course, you might not have to express the update using a subselect; I am just describing the change in terms of adding syntax to the sytax you gave.

UPDATE

You can make a (possibly temporary) table as the x select. Put that table in the FROM. If the table is around while you collecting multiple x argument lists then you can just insert each (cid,mid,name,value) as you get it.

```
INSERT INTO user_config (cid, sid, value)
SELECT cid, id, value
FROM user_settings s JOIN x
ON s.mid=x.mid AND s.name=x.name
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = x.value;
```

Comment: The parameters passed to the x function are taken from the GET parameters (after a lot of messing around with it). So basically I am inserting rows into the `user_config` table, specifying the values for the `cid`, `sid` and `value` columns. The value for `cid` and `value` are taken from an array (`$cid[0]` and `$value[0]` for the first insertion, etc) whereas `sid` is taken from the row in `user_settings` corresponding to `mid=$mid[0]` and `name=$name[0]` etc.

Comment: Does the "messing around" involve accessing the database? How do you come to have "multiple" x values? Are you just saving them up? (I know how you *use* x arguments for *one* call; I wanted to know how you *get* x arguments for *multiple* calls.) See my edited answer.

Comment: @KeirSimmons Updated with code for a table of x argument lists.